# Removal of Pops From Old Optical Tracks

Tags: noise-reduction, snap-crackle-pop

I'm cleaning old optical tracks that have varying amounts of pops. The pops could have resulted from splices or dust on the print.  What are the best Pro Tools plug-ins to remove this type of instantaneous pop? They tend to have the same waveform signature, tornado next to a mountain or some similar variation.  Are there some other stand alone applications that could do the job?

Answer (score 2):

Back when I was restoring old-time radio shows, we had a saying: "sometimes the quickest and most effective noise reduction technique is ripple-delete." If it's an "instantaneous" sound, maybe you can just cut it out...

Comment: The pen tool is effective but on a two hour movie is not only slow but a real cramp in the hand.  Filling works as well but the original file is not permanently changed.  

Comment: I don't think I suggested the pen tool. 

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your answer.  I'm not familiar with ripple-delete.

Comment: Sorry, obscure reference on my part: Ripple-delete is the Sonic Solutions equivalent of ProTools' Shuffle Mode. IOW, snip out the offending noise and close up the gap. Using this technique with quick clicks and pops, we generally didn't wind up losing anything vital in the edit. (of course, if sync is an issue, find a way to fill the gap instead of moving everything that's south of the edit.)


Answer (score 1):

iZotope RX 2, no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

iZotope RX 2, Wave Arts Master Restoration, or (if you have the budget) CEDAR CT16.

Comment: I bought iZotope RX2 and find it incredibly effective.  I'm working on a classic 1954 American film in various languages with old optical tracks.  Izotope obliterates the pops and clicks with no discernible affect on the EQ.  What a time saver! 
Thanks to all for your help.  

Comment: Very happy to help. I've been using RX since about late 2007 :)